# How to merge two datasets in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

I am currently working to merge two datasets in `R`. The first is a cross-national longitudinal dataset of democracy scores and inequality levels for countries over hundreds of years (15,034 observations, `dat_as`). The second is a cross-national longitudinal dataset of whether a given country in a given year has a legislature (27,192 observations, `dat_vdem`). I want to attach the legislatures data to the inequality data. The goal is to have a final `df` with the same number of observations (15,034). If there is a match, merge the data. If there is not a match, just insert an `NA` for the row. Every approach I have tried in `R` does not work. For example, using this code I get a `df` with 2,558,975 observations.

```
# load data
dat_as <- read.csv("as.csv")
dat_vdem <- read.csv("vdem.csv")

# merge 
test_df <- merge(dat_as, dat_vdem, by = c("code"))
```

Using this code, however, I get a `df` with 13,355 observations.

```
test_df <- merge(dat_as, dat_vdem, by = c("country", "year"))
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated. Below are reproducible data.

Here is the `dat_as`:

```
structure(list(X = 1:6, country = c("United States", "United States", 
"United States", "United States", "United States", "United States"
), year = 1800:1805, scode = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA"), code = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), democracy = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), lagdemocracy = c(NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    lbmginiint = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), lbmgdppint = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), ldemlbmginiint = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ldemlbmgdppint = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), yearsq = c(3240000, 
    3243601, 3247204, 3250809, 3254416, 3258025), legislature = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here is the `dat_vdem`:

```
structure(list(X = 1:6, year = 1800:1805, country = c("United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States", "United States"), code = c("USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "USA"), v2lgbicam = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), v2lgqstexp = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_), v2lgotovst = c(-2.1, -2.1, -2.1, -2.1, -2.1, 
-2.1), v2lginvstp = c(-2.05, -2.05, -2.05, -2.05, -2.05, -2.05
), legislature = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your example dput doesn't work because there are no matching 'code' or 'country', 'year' with those data showed.  The `merge` by default is inner_join.  If you need a left_join, you may have to specify `all.x = TRUE`.  Also, if the column matches have duplicates, this will expand the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing a left join. The way I find easier is to use `dplyr`.

`dplyr::left_join(dat_as, dat_vdem)`.

By default it will try and guess which key variables to match by. With the sample data you provided, it matched by "X", "country", "year", "code", "legislature". But you can specify them if need be.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did exactly what I needed it to do.